# The from address failed :Called Mail() without being connected

Tags: email, yii, smtp

I want to send email from localhost using SMTP mail in Yii Framework. I am already copying PhpMailer into extensions folder. I am following the tutorial to setting the main.php like below

```
'components'=>array(

    'Smtpmail'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
        'Host'=>"smtp.gmail.com",
        'Username'=>'myGmail@gmail.com',
        'Password'=>'myPassword',
        'Mailer'=>'smtp',
        'Port'=>465,
        'SMTPAuth'=>true, 
        'SMTPSecure' => 'ssl'
    ),
```

Then, in my controller :

```
            $mail=Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
            $mail->SetFrom('myGmail@gmail.com', 'My Name');
            $mail->Subject= $subject;
            $mail->MsgHTML($email);
            $mail->AddAddress($to, "");
```

The browser give me an error : 
The following From address failed: myGmail@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected.
What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

for smtp.gmail.com try using 587 for port and tls for SMTPsecure

```
'Smtpmail'=>array(
    'class'=>'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
    'Host'=>"smtp.gmail.com",
    'Username'=>'myGmail@gmail.com',
    'Password'=>'myPassword',
    'Mailer'=>'smtp',
    'Port'=>'587',    // or 587
    //'SMTPAuth'=>true, 
    'SMTPAuth'=>false, 
    'SMTPSecure' => 'tls'
),
```

,

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge. I Try that but I get another error. 
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: Try with SMTPAuth = false or with commenting SMTPAuth

Comment: Yes, I try but I got another error. Property "CWebApplication.smtpmail" is not defined.
I use windows OS not Linux. Is PHPmailer compatible with Windows OS?

Comment: Or, Is There other requirement that I didn't install ?

Comment: You are sure of the fact you have a gmail accont like you are using. ? (username and password) and this is not a secondary account. try with you configuration too.  seems correct

Comment: I am sure my username and password is valid. what do yoou mean secondary account?

Comment: mean you have one account gmail only

Comment: Do you know other Yii extension wich I can send email from my localhost beside smtpmail and PHPMailer? I try both, but they didn't work.

Comment: You're using Yii1? which version?

Comment: Yes. It is version 1.1.16

Comment: Take a  look athis http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/ or at this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dpsmailer/